# peek of closed file error while reading a binary file

Tags: python, pickle, file-handling

I am trying to insert some data from files into a MySQL database. However, while reading a file it shows an error.

This is my code for inserting into the database from files to a MySQL database:

```
import mysql.connector
import pickle
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='PETROL',
                                         user='Sarthak',
                                         password='q1w2e3r4t5')
    cursor = connection.cursor ( )
    print(connection)
    fp1 = open ("D:/Python/petrol/pdate/pdate.txt" , "rb+")
    pv=[]
    while True :
        try :
            pdate = pickle.load (fp1)
            pv.append(pdate)
        except EOFError :
            for i in pv:
                ins = ("INSERT INTO DATES (Date) VALUES (%(i)s)")
                data ={'i' : i}
                cursor.execute(ins,data)
            fp1.close ()
        connection.commit()
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to create table in MySQL: {}".format(error))
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

This kind of error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/sarth/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 14, in <module>
    pdate = pickle.load (fp1)
ValueError: peek of closed file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not come out of the `While` loop, and the `fp1` pointer has already been closed when dealing with `EOFError`, you are getting this error.

One way to resolve this would be to `break` out of the `while` loop when encountering the `EOFError`.

So the code becomes:

```py
except EOFError :
            for i in pv:
                ins = ("INSERT INTO DATES (Date) VALUES (%(i)s)")
                data ={'i' : i}
                cursor.execute(ins,data)
            fp1.close ()
            break
```